# rename a connected action

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, rename, ibaction

How do I rename a connected action and remaining it connected?

These are the steps I tried and failed:

1. On my `UIViewController` placed a button
2. I created the action by pressing control +click on the button drag to empty line in the code
3. `UIViewController` .m file -> rename the action -> the connection was lost (empty circle beside the function)
4. Pressing control +click on the button drag to the function name/body -> failed to connect
5. Right clicking on the button and remove the the old connection by pressing the X -> repeat step 4 -> failed to connect
6. Right clicking on the button in the correct set event placed the mouse on the empty circle when it turned to '+' repeated step 4 -> failed

The strange thing is that when dragging to a different connected action name/body it does allow connection.

Other than opening the storyboard file in text editor and change the function name is there something I can do from the `IDE`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried *Refactoring* it?

Answer (score 7):

### It is called `Refactoring`

1. Click with right mouse button on outlet name in .h or .m file
2. `Refactor`
3. `Rename`
4. Type needed name

Comment: Thanks it works :) i think you ment right click on the action cause i don't have an outlet, and the action is only in the .m file (is there a way to have an action in the h file?)

Comment: You can rename variables with `Rename` function only when select it's name in your code, so it's depend on where your variable referred.

Comment: Gutted that Xcode 6.1 does not support similar Obj-C refactoring utilities for Swift :(